# Use navbar with .container class and place additional dropdown just outside container without offsetting container alignment

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, navbar

**Desired output**: two rows, each with a .container div, aligned in center of viewport (and each other). Navbar in 2nd row .container.   Additionally I want to add one more, non-collapsing dropdown to the end of that navbar row outside the .container, at edge of viewport, without de-centering the container.

**Current output**:  with the additional dropdown the .container with the navbar is pushed to the left and not centered with the .container in the header directly above.

I'm doing this to add a custom header to a product that is switching to bootstrap 5 and places their content in a .container.

```
 |---------viewport----------|
 |-    |  .container   |    -|
 |-  |  .container   |     xx|
 |-    |  .container   |    -|
 |-    |  .container   |    -|
 |---------viewport----------|
```

*I want the **'xx'** in the above diagram to not push the adjacent container to the left, and instead to allow the adjacent container to remain aligned with all other containers.*

This is what I have tried [Codepen example here](https://codepen.io/ddd4n4/pen/ZEPMXNL)   I like how this collapses but not how it displays on full screen. (I've added vertical left/right border lines to each of the two containers for visibility )

[Screenshot of expanded view - note bottom-row container is not aligned with top container due to inclusion of Help drop-down on far-right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dsDz.png)

```html
<!--Branding area-->

    <div id="branding-area" class="header-branding" class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="container" id="branding-container">
            <div class="row">
                 
                 <div class="col-lg-1 djc-branding-box">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block" src="https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/customers/1929/images/blank-logo-1.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-11" style="font-size: 20px; color: #fff; text-align: center;">
                        <div id="header-links" class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="right_bar">
                          <li class="right_bar_item"><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li class="right_bar_item">·</li>
                          <li class="right_bar_item"><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                            <li class="right_bar_item">·</li>
                          <li class="right_bar_item"><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    
    
    
<!-- navbar area -->
    
    <nav id="djc-navbar-area" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
      <div id="navbar-container" class="container-fluid container">
      
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Local Branch</a>
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                About
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Resources
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Services
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Account
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        
        </div>
      
        <div id="hours"  style="color: #fff; font-size: 20px;" class="ms-md-auto ms-sm text-sm-start">
          Today's hours: 9:00 - 5:00
        </div>
         
      </div>
      
      <!-- want this dropdown in the navbar but outside centered .container -->
      <ul  id="djc-help" class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 float-end btn btn-danger">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Help &amp; Chat
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </nav>
```

```css
/*show .container l-r boundaries*/
#branding-container {  
  border-left: 1px solid #fff; 
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

#navbar-container{
  border-left: 1px solid #fff; 
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}


#branding-area {
    background-color: #CE1126;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#djc-navbar-area {
  background-color:#333;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: ariel, helvitica, verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#djc-navbar-area a
{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: ariel, helvitica, verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#djc-help {border-radius: 0;}

/* space that contains links */
.right_bar {
    float: right;
    font-family: CaeciliaCom-75Bold,cambria,Palatino Linotype,Book Antiqua,Palatino,serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.right_bar_item, .right_bar_item a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.navbar {
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. Need more clarity what is expected and what is the current output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out the "Help & Chat" menu out of the document flow in order to achieve this. Changing this line:

```
  <ul  id="djc-help" class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 float-end btn btn-danger">
```

to this:

```
  <ul  id="djc-help" class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0 position-absolute end-0 btn btn-danger">
```

will do the trick. Notice how the "Help & Chat" menu is taller than the navbar-container. This is because it's now outside the document flow. You can fix this either by making the navbar-container taller or by making the "Help & Chat" menu a bit shorter, by reducing the top and bottom padding, for example.

Comment: thanks - I updated the padding as suggested.  the absolute positioning  does indeed address the problem when in large displays but in collapsed display the button then overlays the navbar-toggler as can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/ddd4n4/pen/mdoQadZ?editors=1100)

Comment: Not much you can do about it, I'm afraid. You can try repositioning the button when the screen shrinks or leave enough margin/padding on the navbar for the button.